# Rails sidekiq em produção

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fila, redis

Estou tentando botar e produção uma APP que utiliza o Redis e o Sidekiq para jobs em filas.
Em desenvolvimento ele funciona da seguinte maneira. Rodo o comando no terminal:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q default
```

e deixo rodando. 
Quando envio os processos para a fila, pelo Rails é execultado automaticamente os jobs. 
Mas no servidor de produção não consegui fazer funcionar da mesma maneira. até porque a conexão é SSH. não sei se tem quem configurar o comando de inicio do consumo, dentro do próprio Rails. Ou se é da mesma forma que em desenvolvimento, abrindo um terminal com conexão SSH e deixo lá rodando. Mas ai caio em outra dúvida. e se o servidor reiniciar? Tanto o Redis server como sidekiq estão sendo executados de forma manual. Meu Servidor Web é Apache2 e Passenger. Ruby version 2.2.3 e Rails 4.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em production você deve rodar o Sidekiq em background (através do parametro -d) e deve também indicar o arquivo onde será gravado o log do sidekiq.

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L sidekiq.log -e production
```

Onde você vai rodar isso depende muito de como você esta fazendo esse deploy. Se for no capistrano, existem os hooks para rodar pra você.

Comment: Deu certo. já havia tentado com o -d mas estava dando erro. acredito que era pq não tinha indicado o arquivo de log. Muito obrigado Pedro Moreira Mamede